# Kafka automation Java when service is producing the messages

Tags: java, testing, apache-kafka, automation, message

I would like to automate the Kafka messages that are produced by the API service. Can someone please provide your insights on it?

1. Fire a REST API request
2. kafka messages are getting published as a producer in the logs
3. need to get those messages from logs & validate them

Comment: Which messages? Which api service? You'll need to provide more details on what you're trying to do?

Comment: You are asking a question as if we work in your team. we now nothing about your need, give more details like @KevinHooke said..

Comment: Sorry guys, updated my question which is very basic as this is the first time trying to automate kafka messages, already looking into some of the below:
1. https://knowledge.zerocode.io/knowledge/kafka-testing-introduction
2. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-kafka-testing
But I want something as mentioned in the description above.

Comment: Still unclear what you mean by "automate". Sounds like you want to mock/call a REST API that includes a Kafka Producer... If so, use Wiremock as a starting point that includes a Kafka producer. Otherwise, please edit your question to include the code and exact issues you're running into

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got an answer by myself & team and posting it here for any descendants,
from the below 2nd line, once messages are returned, need to write own assertions to validate whether the kafka message is valid & in correct format in JSON or not.

```
KafkaPicker kafkaPicker = new KafkaPicker("Charging", properties);
ConsumerRecords<Object, Object> messages = kafkaPicker.returnAll();
System.out.println("Charging topic messages are : " + messages);
kafkaPicker.close();


public class KafkaPicker implements AutoCloseable {
private static final Duration POLL_TIMEOUT = Duration.ofSeconds(1);
private final String topicName;
private final KafkaConsumer<Object, Object> consumer;

public KafkaPicker(String topicName, Properties properties) {
    this.topicName = topicName;
    consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
}

public void readSpecific(Long offset, Integer partition) {
    TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition(topicName, partition);
    consumer.assign(Collections.singletonList(topicPartition));
    consumer.seek(topicPartition, offset);
    ConsumerRecords<Object, Object> records = consumer.poll(POLL_TIMEOUT);
    records.forEach(a -> System.out.println(a.value()));
}

public void readAll() {
    TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition(topicName, 0);
    List<TopicPartition> partitions = Collections.singletonList(topicPartition);
    consumer.assign(partitions);
    consumer.seekToBeginning(partitions);
    ConsumerRecords<Object, Object> records = consumer.poll(POLL_TIMEOUT);
    records.forEach(a -> System.out.println(a.value()));
}

public ConsumerRecords<Object, Object> returnAll() {
    TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition(topicName, 0);
    List<TopicPartition> partitions = Collections.singletonList(topicPartition);
    consumer.assign(partitions);
    consumer.seekToBeginning(partitions);
    boolean size = true;
    ConsumerRecords<Object, Object> records = null;
    while (size) {
        records = consumer.poll(POLL_TIMEOUT);
        if (records.count() != 0)
            size = false;
    }
    return records;
}

public void close() {
    consumer.close();
}
```